# *Woocommerce* Past Orders Disappeared after changing Stripe Account

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I changed my Stripe account in Woocommerce and all my past orders that were made with stripe disappeared. Any ideas?

[image]

As you can see it says “All: 149” but then it says (Items: 44).

So 105 orders disappeared…

Also I don’t see the option to change order status to partially shipped or shipped. What do you think happened to this? Woocommerce offers no support so I'm asking here instead.

Thanks